# Continuously animate element's background

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-color

Is it possible to animate element's background color in loop?

For ex: If we have one `<div>` which has `background-color:red` and through jQuery I change it to `background-color:blue`. Now I want it to `toggle` between red and blue **continuously**.

How can I do it?

Comment: This can be done in a loop. But you need to add some time gap so that human eye can see the transition.

Comment: kinda epilepsy stimulator?

Comment: Y U NO USE CSS TRANSITION?

Comment: @benni_mac_b No in my case it is changing of CSS properties through jQuery and in your suggested post there is a interchanging of two html elements.Its quite a different.

Comment: @AhmadAlfy so how to do it with transition in a loop. Please answer me ??

Comment: @AhmadAlfy yes it works ! definitely i would accept your answer!

Comment: Answers with memes should be = instant acceptance

Comment: @Cherniv check OP's avatar: http://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-I2n8WGCe65U/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAhs/i_njN1P1w7I/s512-c/photo.jpg

Comment: @AhmadAlfy thank you,hey BTW how did you get this link of my avatar. I mean from where and how did you burrowed the link.???

Comment: Ah ho...got it. I was in not taking that thing in account and was thinking how.got it. ☺

Comment: Answer updated! Added JavaScript fallback

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS

```
.divClassRed{
    background-color:red;
}
.divClassBlue{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

jQuery

```
setInterval(function(){
    if($('#myDiv').hasClass('divClassRed')){
        $('#myDiv').addClass('divClassBlue').removeClass('divClassRed');            
    }else{
        $('#myDiv').addClass('divClassRed').removeClass('divClassBlue');
    }

},1000);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eSpFx/2/)

Answer (score 11):

[image: Y U NO DUDE]

```
@keyframes epilepsy {
    from {
        background: red;
        color:blue;
    }
    to {
        background: blue;
        color:red;
    }
}

.element {
    animation-duration: 0.1s;
    animation-name: epilepsy;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

## [Working Demo](http://codepen.io/ahmadalfy/pen/IkKdi)

**Note**: I did not add the vendor prefixes

## Update

[image: If we could get it to work on older browsers, that would be great!]

I went a little bit zealous and included fallback using jQuery and [modernizr](/questions/tagged/modernizr). Note that background-color transition is not supported in jQuery animate by default; [jQuery color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/blob/master/jquery.color.js) is required

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  // Using Modernizr to test if CSS transition is supported or not
  if(!Modernizr.csstransitions){
    setInterval(function() {
      // Go really crazy and do the amazing voodoo using JavaScript
      $('.default').animate({
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        color: 'blue'
      }, 100).animate({
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        color: 'red'
      }, 100); 
    }, 100);
 });

});
```

Comment: @Sowmya You have to add the vendor prefixes. There is a working demo

Comment: @AhmadAlfy I think the size of the pic offended me. Never Mind

Comment: @XeeMezAsHu sorry man, that's the meme generator. resized and uploaded no offense at all

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var x;

     function changecolors() {
         x = 1;
         setInterval(change, 1000);
     }

     function change() {
         if(x == 1) {
             color = "red";
             x = 2;
         } else {
             color = "blue";
             x = 1;
         }

         document.body.style.background = color;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uU4gu/

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('div').css("background-color", "yellow");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('div').css("background-color", "red");
    }, 1000);   
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/SidJadeja/XqwDC/

Just called recursive functions to animate a toggle between red and blue colors continuously. You can modify the duration as per your needs.

JS:

```
function anim() {
    $("body").animate({
        backgroundColor: "darkblue"
    }, {
        duration: 5000,
        complete: function () {
            $("body").animate({
                 backgroundColor: "darkred"
            }, {
                duration: 5000,
                complete: function () {
                    anim();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```